# Parts of a question without parentheses in document class exam

Tags: formatting, lists, exam, parentheses

How to do Parts number of a question without parentheses in document class exam ?

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question 
    \begin{parts}
    \part The sub question 1 ?
    \part The sub question 2 ?  
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Its output will be

1. (a) The sub question 1 ?

   (b) The sub question 2 ?

I need to get the same output without parenthesis for the number of sub questions like

1. a. The sub question 1 ?

   b. The sub question 2 ?

Comment: You need to show us what have done so far by giving a minimal working example starting with a `\documentclass` command, the packages that you are using and `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The MWE should be as small as possible, compile and show how you are,doing a question without parts.

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjust the macro `\partlabel`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}

\renewcommand\partlabel{\thepartno.}% Default is (\thepartno)

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question The question?

  \begin{parts}
    \part The sub question~1?
    \part The sub question~2?
  \end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```